# can an inner function use variables defined in the parent function?

Tags: c, arrays

Can a variable be used in an inner function if it was defined in the outer function? or should i modify the inner loop to take a third parameter which would be the array?

Example of the code i'm asking about?

```
perm_rec1 ( int nr_value , int N)
{
    int array[];
    secondFunction(int nr_value, int N)
}
```

The inner function:

```
secondFunction (int nr_value, int N)
{
    int temp = array; //is This possible? Or third parameter?

}
```

Comment: With an array with a size, Yes, you can passing it to the function as a `int *`

Comment: You have to pass it as a parameter, because what would happen if secondFunction was called from somewhere else? It wouldn't work, so it would be dangerous (not to mention make code very hard to read) if you were able to access variables from the calling function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can a variable be used in an inner function if it was defined in the outer function?

C does not have nested functions, which is the only sense in which the "inner" and "outer" designations would make sense.  When one function calls another, as in your example, it is the *call* that is "inside" the first function, not the called function.

In any event, variables declared at block scope, such as in your example, are visible only within the remainder of the lexical extent of the declaring block.  They are not visible in the body of a function called from within that block -- not even if it is the same function, called recursively.

> or should i modify the inner loop to take a third parameter which would be the array?

The most natural implementation would be, yes, to give the function a third parameter by which to provide (a pointer to the first element of) the array to that function.

Answer (score 4):

There is no inner function here (nor there is in C). What you have is a function that calls another one; and no you can't access in the callee something that was defined in the caller except if you pass it explicitly as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Interpreting what you need, you can use pointers to do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test ( int *pointer, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%zu] = %d\n", i, *pointer++);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    test(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any variable declared in the inner block shadows the outer variable declaration.

```
{
int a = 6;
  {
    int a = 9;
    // won't affect the outer declaration
  }
// value of a = 6 here
}
```

But as you are asking there cannot be any inner function in C. Only we can have inner blocks defined within braces.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, it is actually possible to misuse local variables to access the stack frame of a parent function, yes. But this is a very, very ugly solution, set aside platform-dependent. So just pass it as a parameter.